# Unable to seed database with EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am recreating my MVC asp.net core but this time I'm using ASP.NET Identity since it has the register/log-in built in.

The only difference I noticed was the database is a "defaultconnection" in the startup.cs file but I'm not sure why that would change how you seed the database. When I run the project, I don't get any build errors or exceptions but the database does not seed and I get a 404 Error when I try to click on something when running the web app.

This is exactly how my files look in my other ASP.NET Core project and it works properly so I don't know what the issue is here. If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Here is my **Startup.cs** file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EasyEats.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using EasyEats.Models;

namespace EasyEats
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            //SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);

        }
    }
}
```

I read that the last line (SeedData.Initialize) was supposed to seed the database but instead I got an error saying:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[EasyEats.Data.ApplicationDbContext]' from root provider.'
```

So I just commented it out for now.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using EasyEats.Data;
using EasyEats.Models;

namespace EasyEats
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();


            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    SeedData.Initialize(services);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**SeedData.cs** (in models folder)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using EasyEats.Data;

namespace EasyEats.Models
{
    public class SeedData
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
                serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<
                    DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
            {
                // Look for any movies.
                if (context.Restaurants.Any())
                {
                    return;   // DB has been seeded
                }

                context.Restaurants.AddRange(
                    new Restaurant
                    {
                        RestaurantName = "McDonalds",
                        RestaurantDescription = "McDonald's Corporation sells hamburgers, chicken sandwiches, French fries, soft drinks, breakfast items, and desserts.",
                    },

                    new Restaurant
                    {
                        RestaurantName = "Burger King",
                        RestaurantDescription = "Burger King Corporation, restaurant company specializing in flame-broiled fast-food hamburgers.",
                    },

                    new Restaurant
                    {
                        RestaurantName = "Chipotle",
                        RestaurantDescription = "Chipotle is a fast-casual chain that's known for its build-your-own burritos, rice bowls, and other Mexican dishes.",
                    },

                    new Restaurant
                    {
                        RestaurantName = "Chick-fil-A",
                        RestaurantDescription = "Chick-fil-A is one of the largest American fast food restaurant chains and the largest whose specialty is chicken sandwiches.",
                    }
                );
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using EasyEats.Models;

namespace EasyEats.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm using two tutorials as references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a web stack, not a data access library or ORM. The tutorials aren't broken either. If you don't register the DbContexts, you can't retrieve them with `GetService`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I followed the tutorials unless you see something I missed? Plus most of this auto-generated when you create a project with ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact,you just need to delete the code in you `Program.cs`:

```
CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Then re-run your project and check the database.

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly fine now!

Comment: Yup `WebHost.Run()` is a blocking method so the program will not get past the first line in your `Main` without pressing ctrl+C first

Answer (score 0):

You register your `ApplicationDbContext` twice in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
 services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>();
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                      options.UseSqlServer(
                              Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Try removing the scoped registration and check if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I got an error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[EasyEats.Data.ApplicationDbContext]' from root provider.'

Comment: @AnaSyan using what code? Because `AddDbContext` alone works. I'm using a dozen DbContext instances in a project right now, all defines through `AddDbContext`. The error you got means that you *didn't* call `AddDbContext` when you should have. Or used the wrong `ApplicationDbContext`. Have you mixed up the namespaces perhaps? Tried to use an `ApplicationDbContext` from another project?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay I just cleaned the solution after removing the scoped registration and now I don't get the error but the database is still null.